# Calculating average variance extracted (AVE) in AMOS discriminant validity

Tags: variance, discriminant-analysis

I was asked to calculate average variance extracted (AVE) to establish discriminant validity; I've ran CFA but ask how to calculate AVE following Fornell & Larcker’s (1981) test when having two latent variables.

Comment: Here the link to download an excel file to calculate AVE etc:
[Manual Calculation for SEM](http://www.watoowatoo.net/sem/sem.html)